# Не работает socket.io на сервере

Tags: socket.io, node.js

На локалке работает отлично.

На сервере не хочет. Ошибка 400.

Nginx настроил, node.js запустил.

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen         5.187.7.164:80;
    server_name    p.domaio.ru www.p.domaio.ru;

    location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|key|html|woff|ico|ttf|eot|mp3|svg|txt)$ {
        root /var/www/bumbay/data/node/p.domaio.ru/public;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8092;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        proxy_pass http://5.187.7.164:8002;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-for  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
...
io.connect($location.host() == 'p.domaio.ru' ? 'p.domaio.ru' : 'localhost:8092', {
    reconnection: true,
    'sync disconnect on unload': true,
    forceNew: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 200,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 1500
});
...
```

**server.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8092);
```

Я пробовал не проксировать socket.io. Тоже самое.

Я менял конфиг nginx в любые варианты, которые находил в гугле.

Но когда я прописывал

```
transports: ['websocket', 'polling']
```

Ошибки не было. Запрос завершался, соединение не устанавливалось. Ответ пуст. И потом я пробовал менять nginx.

Ничего не помогает.

http://src.unotes.ru/g/d1dwf.png

Comment: Порт, на который повешен сокет.ио, на сервере разрешен к прослушиванию?

Comment: @deivan, порт node и socket одинаковый.

Comment: @exec, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, обновил.